# Toshiba Satellite l355-s7011 won't power up

Tags: laptop, power-supply

My Toshiba Satellite l355-s7011 will not power up.  How do I fix it? The DC port came out.  I think it was dropped.  I opened it up and everything looks fine but it doesn't power up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's broken it's broken. Check the power supply, otherwise I would call Toshiba Technical Support and have them diagnose it and advise you on potential fixes. That's what their technical support line is for.

If it's out of warranty, and you *suspect* the DC port is the problem you can try this http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop/2007/12/06/dc-power-jack-repair-guide/